# # in $_Post, $_Get or $_Request results in empty variable

Tags: php, post, get

If I try to submit a piece of text from a form that starts with # - or using GET, I don't get any data. Any idea what is going on here?

URL: {blah}/test.php?test1=foo&test2=#bar

Entire PHP Code:

```
echo $_REQUEST['test1'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_REQUEST['test2'];
echo '<br/>';

var_dump($_GET);
```

Gives this in the browser:

> foo
>
> array(2) { ["test1"]=> string(3) "foo" ["test2"]=> string(0) "" }

If I write some more text before the # e.g. "foo #bar" then I get "foo"

Comment: You have to encode your url before posting

Comment: I've just realised all my queries were actually GETs.  POST does work.  I think it's a useful question though because I've been programming PHP for years and never noticed this before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` character in a URL has special meaning. It indicates the start of the fragment identifier.

You need to percent encode it (as `%23`) if you want to include it as data.